# How to fix mat-list-item not taking full space of row

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Hello guys I rendering an article.component.html inside my article-list-component.html in a list when I do it in plain HTML it renders just fine (see picture 1):
Title   - author -                        Date
Here is my article-list.component.html

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let article of data_array">
        <a [href]="article.url" class="undecorateda" target="_blank">
            <app-article [data]='article'></app-article>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but when I try to use angular-material list the component renders all to the left like this (see picture 2):
Title-author-Date
Here is my article-list.component html:

```html
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let article of data_array">
        <a [href]="test">
            <app-article [data]='article' (click)="printURL(article.url)"></app-article>
        </a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

when I use the plain HTML in the article-list.component.html it renders as I want it to do, but if I use the material code inside article-list.component.html it doesn't render properly

this is the article.component.html

```html
<div class='article-container'>

    <div class='title-container'>
        {{data.title}}
        <div class='author-container'>
            -{{data.author}}-
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='date-container'>
        {{formatDay(data.created_at)}}
    </div>

    <div class="actions-container" id="deletebtn">
        <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="deleteArticle(data._id)">
            <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

this is the article.component.css file:

```css
.article-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: 10fr 2fr 1fr;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.article-container>* {
    grid-row: 1/2;
}

.article-container #deletebtn {
    display: none;
}

.article-container:hover {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.article-container:hover #deletebtn {
    display: block;
}

.title-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

.author-container {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.date-container {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

.title-container div {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Basically what I want is to use material-angular list inside the article-list.component.html and that it render good like in picture 1
[image: Picture#1-Good rendering]
[image: Picture#2-Bad rendering]

==========================================

Comment: Could you create your issue on StackBlitz please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a width of 100% to the article component itself it should ensure the component takes the whole width and the list will the whole width as well.

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at this example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-list-width) to see the list taking 100% of the width.